# Authlib flask client: problem parsing id token

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, authlib

I'm trying to connect a Flask application to a 3rd-party OAuth2 service using authlib and the authlib flask client. The auth service returns a JWT with the following header:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "appId-1030324f-bb91-4b2a-b5fb-ae255b8142e0-2020-04-27T20:27:44.769",
  "ver": 4
}
```

The token works fine if I paste it into [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), but when I pass it to `parse_id_token` in the authlib flask client I get the following exception:

```
authlib.jose.errors.InvalidHeaderParameterName: invalid_header_parameter_name: Invalid Header Parameter Names: ver
```

I looked at [RFC 7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) (section 4, JOSE header) and while `ver` is not one of the registered parameter headers the spec does say:

```
Unless listed as a critical Header Parameter, per
   Section 4.1.11, all Header Parameters not defined by this
   specification MUST be ignored when not understood.
```

Is there some configuration parameter I can pass to authlib to make it ignore this header parameter ? I tried looking through the code but haven't found one yet.

Comment: Please try with the latest Authlib. It should ignore the invalid header now.

Comment: Thanks @lepture !  For other - this problem occurred in Authlib 0.14.1 but it is now fixed in 0.14.3.